# My js validation doesn't stop spring boot and just skips

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to stop my spring boot controller work while js validation is correct. And i dont understand why it shows for a second and then disappears and my spring boot application continues to work. How can I fix that? I try all i can but i dont know js to much   maybe it is some wrong with return or something of it?
js code:

```
const form = document.forms[0];
let fieldPassword = document.querySelector('#password');
let fieldConfirmPassword = document.querySelector('#userConfirmPassword');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

    validPassword();
    checkPasswordMatch();

    if(!validPassword()) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    if (!checkPasswordMatch()){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
})
function validPassword() {
    let fieldPasswordValue = fieldPassword.value.trim();

    if (fieldPasswordValue == "") {
        setErrorFor(fieldPassword, "Password cannot be blank");
    }
    else if (!isPassword(fieldPasswordValue)) {
        setErrorFor(fieldPassword, "Min 8 characters, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special symbol");
    }
    else {
        setSuccessFor(fieldPassword);
    }
    function setErrorFor(input, message) {
        let passwordError = input.parentElement.querySelector(".error-message");
        passwordError.innerHTML = message;
    }
    function setSuccessFor(input) {
        let passwordError = input.parentElement.querySelector(".error-message");
        passwordError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    function isPassword(input) {
        const passwordPattern = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/;
        return passwordPattern.test(String(input));
    }
}
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    if (fieldConfirmPassword.value != fieldPassword.value) {
        setErrorFor(fieldConfirmPassword, "Passwords do not match!");
    }
    else if (fieldConfirmPassword.value == "") {
        setErrorFor(fieldConfirmPassword, "Password cannot be blank");
    }
    else if (!isPassword(fieldPassword.value)) {
        setErrorFor(fieldPassword, "Min 8 characters, one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number and one special symbol");
        setErrorFor(fieldConfirmPassword, "");
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(fieldConfirmPassword);
        form.submit();
    }
    function setErrorFor(input, message) {
        let passwordError = input.parentElement.querySelector(".error-message");
        passwordError.innerHTML = message;
    }
    function setSuccessFor(input) {
        let passwordError = input.parentElement.querySelector(".error-message");
        passwordError.innerHTML = "";
    }
    function isPassword(input) {
        const passwordPattern = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$/;
        return passwordPattern.test(String(input));
    }
}
```

Comment: Spring-boot is not involved in this. Once the JavaScript makes the actual call SpringBoot, of course, abides. The problem is in the JS, so I removed the unrelated tags.

Comment: Back to your problem: your `validPassword` and `checkPasswordMatch` methods don't return anything, so using them as the conditions in your `if`s is completely useless. Also, `checkPasswordMatch` does a submit on its own.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca can you please advice where put return true of false. Now I have correct validPassword but my checkPasswordMatch doesnt work

Comment: I'd say return `true` inside the `else`s in those two methods, and `false` at the end of each method, so that if there was *any* error `false` is returned. Also, it would be clearer if you didn't define other methods inside your method. There's no practical reason for them to be there and most of the code is duplicated anyway.